# I need to check for duplicates of a column in a separate column and filter out the non-duplicate alone

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

There are duplicates in a column. I need a separate column which shows the records that have duplicates. Then I need to have a slicer filter which shows the records that occur only once and label them as Non-duplicates and rest as duplicates.

There is a column called concat_username_userinvoice (I had performed the concatenate function for the 2 columns). Now I checked for records which occur more than once using this formula as shown below

Count_duplicates = CALCULATE(COUNT('SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice]),FILTER('SK-RAW',[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice]=EARLIER('SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice])))

The expected result is as attached in the pic. In the result the count_duplicates column throws the number of counts each record repeats like 1,2,4,5...Now I need to filter out the records which occur only once in the concat_username_userinvoice  and label them as non-duplicates or should I use some other DAX calculation to directly filter out the distinct records?

Comment: Note that every column reference requires a table name like `'SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice]` and that you didn't attach your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression needs a row context so you have to put it into a **calculated column**

```
Count_duplicates = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice]),
    FILTER(
        'SK-RAW',
        'SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice] = EARLIER('SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice])
    )
)
```

and then filter on

```
'SK-RAW'[Count_duplicates] = 1
```

Alternatively, you could create a **calculated table** with

```
Distinct Names = 
DISTINCT('SK-RAW'[Concat_UserName_UserInvoice])
```